# PHP - what can cause ssh2_connect() unable to connect error

Tags: php, network-programming

I have installed the ssh2 extension and even have it enabled. i have also enabled openssl. Everything seems fine, but when i try to connect to a server i am getting ssh2_connect() unable to connect error. The server i am trying to access is accessible from my machine, i connected to the server via the terminal but when i run the script on my machine it is unable to connect to the server, any ideas what is going wrong here ?

I would appreciate it if you guys could point out som possible reasons that i can check/debug!

My script is like this:

`$connection = ssh2_connect('shell.example.com', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');`

PS: i know there is a libary(phpseclib) that i can use, but i want to use ssh2 extension

Thanks :) !

Comment: and this script is running... where? being able to connect from one machine means very little if there's a firewall in the mix.

Comment: the script is running on my machine, locally. if it was the firewall that was blocking the connection then i would not be able to access it from the terminal either right ?

Comment: Turn on `error_reporting(E_ALL)`. What error do you get from `ssh2_connect`?

Comment: Maybe this question is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14372529/php-ssh-how-can-i-fix-error-ssh2-connect-error-starting-up-ssh-connectio